# unindent does not match any outer indentation level, why is this happening

Tags: python, indentation

Here is my code:

```
import urllib
import re
import requests
import httplib
import socket
from colorama import *
from time import gmtime, strftime
  def hell():
    hcon = raw_input(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "Website: ")
    r = requests.get("http://" + hcon + "/phpmyadmin")
    r2 = requests.get("http://" + hcon + "/pma")
    if r.status_code == 404:
     print(strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", gmtime()) + " /phpmyadmin/ not found!") 
    elif r: 
     print(strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", gmtime()) + " /phpmyadmin/ successfully found! %s /phpmyadmin") % (hcon)
    elif r2:
     print(strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", gmtime()) + " /phpmyadmin/ successfully found! %s /pma") % (hcon)
    else:
     print(strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", gmtime()) + " nothing found, sorry! try another website.")

hell()
```

As you can see, If the page /phpmyadmin  or /pma exists on the selected website it will output that it was successfully found, If not it will say "nothing found etc etc.."

But I get this error: unindent does not match outer indentation level, I have never occurred this error in any of my previous python scripts.

I've tried to fix the indentation as much as I can but I don't think that will solve it, Can someone help?

Comment: It looks like you've modified the code; when I paste it and try to run it locally I instead get "unexpected indent" on the "def hell()" line.  Naturally, to fix that you need to move the def block back a couple of spaces, as the answers suggest.

However, the error you describe is different, and typically shows up when you have a line indented by X spaces, then some indented by X+Y+Z spaces, and finally one indented by X+Y spaces.  Whenever you dedent, Python requires you to go back to the same level as one of your previous ones.

Comment: I did that but I copied and pasted some of my code, not all. I did do that but the problem is I still get the error @WalterMundt

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the `hell` method definition must be at the root indentation level.

Comment: Update your question with your new code, so that way we can help with more efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

def hell() and everything below should have 1 indentation less.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a comment since this is now answer-ish.

So the code you pasted is incomplete, so I can't give a direct fix for the error you're getting.

Your error typically shows up when you have a line indented by X spaces, then some indented by X+Y+Z spaces, and finally one indented by X+Y spaces. Whenever you dedent, Python requires you to go back to the same level as one of your previous ones.  For example:

```
def foo():
    print "hi!"
  return 42
```

Notice that the return statement's indent is 2 spaces, but no previous line is indented by 2 spaces.  This isn't allowed, and it needs to be indented out to 4 spaces, or the print statement moved back to line up at 2 spaces in.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed spaces and tabs. Try opening your code in Notepad or something with an 8-space indentation level and see what it looks like. It definitely doesn't match what you've posted, or you'd be getting "unexpected indent" errors rather than unindent problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the indentation of `def hell()`:

```
import urllib
import re
import requests
import httplib
import socket
from colorama import *
from time import gmtime, strftime

def hell():
    hcon = raw_input(Fore.RED + Style.BRIGHT + "Website: ")
    r = requests.get("http://" + hcon + "/phpmyadmin")
    r2 = requests.get("http://" + hcon + "/pma")
    if r.status_code == 404:
        print(strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", gmtime()) + " /phpmyadmin/ not found!") 
    elif r: 
        print(strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", gmtime()) + " /phpmyadmin/ successfully found! %s /phpmyadmin") % (hcon)
    elif r2:
        print(strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", gmtime()) + " /phpmyadmin/ successfully found! %s /pma") % (hcon)
    else:
        print(strftime("[%H:%M:%S]", gmtime()) + " nothing found, sorry! try another website.")

hell()
```